# Android: Dropbox sdk - Not able to fetch thumbnail

Tags: java, android, sdk, thumbnails, dropbox

I want to use dropbox API sdk to display images in user's dropbox account, in app.
I have this function, which will fetch the inputStream and return the bitmap of the thumbnail of that particular image on dropbox account.

```
    protected Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromDBStream(String path) {
        // path = "/Photos/2130.jpg"
        DropboxInputStream stream = null;
        try {
            stream = mApi.getThumbnailStream(path, ThumbSize.ICON_128x128, ThumbFormat.JPEG);
        } catch (DropboxException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream);
    }
```

But this is giving me a FileNotFoundException

```
05-02 16:54:24.697: E/BitmapFactory(11562): Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Photos/2130.jpg: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

I can see this file in my dropbox account. Some help needed here. Either I am misunderstanding the function getThumbnailStream or something else.

Comment: Check the path. I think you don't have permissions to write in that path. Give more details about the location where you download the thumbnail.

You can check this: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(java.lang.String)